# Validation for mobile number input

Tags: javascript

I want to make restriction on mobile number and I have to form contain mobile number, I want to set one of these input that match the constraint in var mobileInput and make some validation on it, but I can't make || why? And how I can make this?

```
var mobileInput = input.attr('id') === "mobile-number" || input.attr('id') === "student_mobile";

if (mobileInput) {
    return validateMobileInput(input, formGroup);

function validateEmailInput(input, formGroup) {
var emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
var validEmail = emailRegex.test(input.val());
if (validEmail) {
    successInput(formGroup);
} else {
    errorInput(formGroup, "Email is incorrect");
}
return validEmail;
}
```

Comment: What does `validateEmailInput` have to do with this? Why do you think that the *id* of the input element will change based on the user input?!

Comment: no i use 2 form in different html page and both have mobile number

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Try to log `input.attr('id')`, maybe it does not have the values you are expecting.

Comment: i will try , thank you